# When I try to escape a double quote in C# I get multiple instead of just one

Tags: c#, csv

For the purposes of my program, I need to read in data from a CSV file, process it, and then create a new batch of CSV files based on the data I read in.  I am using the [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) library if that makes a difference.

The program works perfectly, except for one part.  I need my output CSV files to have each field wrapped in double quotes.  Normally I would just use the escape mechanism for c#, but I ran into a bizarre issue that I can't seem to work around.  Whenever I try to escape a " mark, I end up getting more than just the one.

Desired output example:

```
date_start,date_end,current_year
"2017-08-01","2018-06-20","2017"
"2017-08-01","2018-06-20","2017"
```

Observed output:

```
date_start,date_end,current_year
"""2017-08-01""","""2018-06-20""","""2017"""
"""2017-08-01""","""2018-06-20""","""2017"""
```

It puts in a pair of double quotes when I am just looking for one.  I've looked around online and tried several different approaches to try and get just the one double quote, but I can't seem to make it work.  Here is the relevant code and the different methods I have tried:

```
HashSet<CustomDataWrapper> hs = new HashSet<CustomDataWrapper>();

foreach (CustomDataType record in records) {
string quote = "\"";
String method1 = (String)(record.date_start);
String method2 = quote + record.date_start + quote;
String method3 = "\"" + record.date_start + "\"";
String method4 = "\U0022" + record.date_start + "\U0022"

hs.Add(data);
}

csvWriter.WriteRecords(hs);
```

I am honestly not sure what's going on here, as I've tried adding the quote to just one side of the string and got this output:

```
date_start,date_end,current_year
"2017-08-01""","2018-06-20""","2017"""
"2017-08-01""","2018-06-20""","2017"""
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: In CSV, if you want double quotes to be *part of the data*, they must be doubled up as you're seeing.  This is correct.  If you wanted strings that don't actually contain quotes, don't add quotes to the data.

Comment: According to most "standard" definitions of the CSV format, those quotes aren't needed.  And your library chooses to omit them.  When you have any character that *must* be quoted, such as a quote or comma, inside the string, the library will quote it.  But then you have an extra undesired special character.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding the question; with [this .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BbBQIZ) I do not observe any 'extra' quotes

Comment: So the only thing that will work without changing the data, is to figure out how to ask your library to output unnecessary quotes.  That may require switching to a different library, if it isn't configurable in this one.  But I see `QuoteAllFields` on [this page](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/configuration/), you should try setting that to true.

Comment: @sab669 its the CSV writer that is writing the extra quotes out.  Your fiddle doesn't write a CSV.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you!  This has resolved the issue I was getting.  I didn't realize the CsvHelper library had built-in functionality that would affect how it wrote quotes and such.  I feel a little dumb for missing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's happening. Let's start with this code:

```
var records = new []
{
    new { H1 = "Foo", H2 = "Bar" },
    new { H1 = "Qaz", H2 = "Waz" }
};

using (var tw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
{
    using (var cw = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(tw))
    {
        cw.WriteRecords(records);
        var output = tw.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

If I run that I get this output:

```
H1,H2
Foo,Bar
Qaz,Waz
```

If I insert one double quote into one field of the source data, like so:

```
var records = new []
{
    new { H1 = "Foo", H2 = "Bar" },
    new { H1 = "Qaz\"", H2 = "Waz" }
};
```

...then the output becomes:

```
H1,H2
Foo,Bar
"Qaz""",Waz
```

The library knows to be able to output a double quote as part of the data then it must wrap the entire field in double quotes **and** it must escape the double quote within the field, turning a single `"` into `""`.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize that CsvHelper was the source of the extra quote marks.  I've gotten it fixed now, thank you so much.

Comment: @andyrichterr - If the answer helped then please tick as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Stop adding quotes to the fields. Try creating configuration object and set the 'QuoteAllFields' to true and pass this object to CSVWriter as below

```
var config = new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration();
config.QuoteAllFields = true;

using (var csvReader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(streamReader, config))
{
}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed in order for it to work as intended.  Thank you!

Comment: This is not working if I use tab delimited?  `var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture){Delimiter = "\t",config.QuoteAllFields = true};`